# Turning off PermitRootLogin in sshd prevents any user to connect

Tags: ssh, debian, root, sshd, vps

I have a Debian bullseye virtual machine in OVH cloud. Allowing ssh login as root is non-secure, so I decided to turn it off in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by commenting out the line `PermitRootLogin yes`. After that I rebooted the server and I couldn’t login with absolutely any user via ssh, not only with root. It asked for a password and then always answered “Permission denied”. Bringing back the configuration line unblocked the users again. Why does this setting affects other users than root?

Comment: Do you have `PasswordAuthentication yes` appended to the end of the file?

Comment: @Maik Adding `PasswordAuthentication yes` doesn't help, but `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes` works. That's quite strange: why the first one stops working when `PermitRootLogin` is `no`?